# Python string to integer value

Tags: python

I'd like to know how to convert strings in Python to their corresponding integer values, like so:

`>>>print WhateverFunctionDoesThis('\x41\x42')`

`>>>16706`

I've searched around but haven't been able to find an easy way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack(">h",'\x41\x42')
(16706,)
>>> struct.unpack(">h",'\x41\x42')[0]
16706
```

For other format chars see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters)

Answer (score 0):

If '\x41\x42' is 16-based num, like AB. You can use string to convert it.

```
import string

agaga = '\x41\x42'
string.atoi(agaga, 16)
>>> 171
```

Sorry if i got you wrong...

Comment: you're right, `'\x41\x42' == 'AB'` and in some universe Jason would ask for `0xAB` result, instead of `0x4142`

Answer (score 0):

ugly way:

```
>>> s = '\x41\x42'
>>> sum([ord(x)*256**(len(s)-i-1) for i,x in enumerate(s)])
16706
```

or

```
>>> sum([ord(x)*256**i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(s))])
```

Comment: I think left shift is nicer than exponents `sum([ord(x)<<(i*8) for i,x in enumerate(reversed(s))])`